# Gpp error : no such file or directory

Tags: c++, atom-editor

I am trying to compile and run my basic c++ code in Atom .
But it shows an error like 
**gpp error : No such file or directory.**
I was referring stack overflow and got some ideas to solve like Adding path of compiler and removing ".h" from "iostream.h".. but failed please help !!

here is the code 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w7BRq.png)

here is the error msg :

"g++: error: gpp: No such file or directory 
 g++: error: compiler: No such file or directory "

thank you for answering ..

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Does it only say "gpp error : No such file or directory"? For me, it is unclear whether it couldn't find a source file, an included header file, or even the gpp itself. (Although, probably not the latter.) To clarify this, you could [edit] your question and copy/paste the complete error message. (If afraid, you may replace personal data by something like "User".)

Comment: May be, related: [g++:error:CreateProcess:No such file or directory](https://github.com/kriscross07/atom-gpp-compiler/issues/26). (Found this and other by google "atom gpp error : No such file or directory".)

Comment: thank you for your response @Scheff . Added the basic practice code and the actual error msg .